# Retrofit content-length received 0 error while sending Base64

Tags: android, base64, square, retrofit

I am trying to send String and Base64 String to server using form-data. But `Retrofit` keep showing me this error:

```
04-07 06:44:19.366    D/Retrofit﹕ ---- ERROR http://localhost/api/reports?auth_token=....

04-07 06:44:19.366    D/Retrofit﹕ java.io.IOException: content-length promised 29149 bytes, but received 0
        at libcore.net.http.RetryableOutputStream.close(RetryableOutputStream.java:49)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:818)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
        at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.readResponse(UrlConnectionClient.java:90)
        at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:48)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:287)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$500(RestAdapter.java:197)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$1.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:243)
        at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:38)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:134)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-07 06:44:19.366    D/Retrofit:    ---- END ERROR
```

My API URL is like this: 
`http://localhost/api/reports?auth_token=""`

And it accept two parameters as form-data

- report-type
- image

Here is my complete codes:

ReportService

```
public interface ReportService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/reports")
    void report(@Query("auth_token") String authToken, @Field("report_type") String report_type, @Field("image") String image, Callback<Report> callback);
}
```

Report API

```
public class ReportAPI {
    public static ReportAPI mInstance;
    private Context mContext;
    private ReportService mService;

public ReportAPI(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;

    final RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setServer(Constants.BASE_URL).build();
    restAdapter.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);
    mService = restAdapter.create(ReportService.class);
}

public static ReportAPI getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new ReportAPI(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public ReportService getService() {
    return mService;
}
```

Report

```
void report() {
    String authToken = pref.getAuthToken();
    String base64String = ""; //base64 string goes here

    ReportAPI.getInstance(this).getService().report(authToken, "in", base64String, new Callback<Report>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Report report, Response response) {
            Log.e("Report", "Reported Date: " + report.report_in_date);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.e("Report", error.getResponse() + ": Error");
        }
    });
}
```

The request go like this:

```
---> HTTP POST http://localhost/api/reports?auth_token=
04-07 06:58:14.912    D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
04-07 06:58:14.912    D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Length: 29149
04-07 06:58:14.916    D/Retrofit﹕ report_type=in&image=...base64string_goes_here...
04-07 06:58:14.916    D/Retrofit﹕ ---> END HTTP (29149-byte body)
```

I was like 4 days, trying to figure out this problem.

On the side note: I tried to use `TypedString` and `TypedInput` too.

Comment: Does changing the parameter in the fields changes the value 29149? Change the base64 String to "xxx" with different length and try. This will confirm whether the problem is as mentioned below.

Comment: Can also be a problem on server side.

Comment: @DeBuGGeR Of course, that value is changing based on data. And The api works perfectly with PostMan.

Comment: No, I am not using it.

Comment: I remember problems like this in developing for android using Url or HTTP Client, 2 natively available libraries for http. Can u try putting okhttp in the path, this will make sure that the OKhttpClient is used.  Just helping u to troubleshoot because I have used retrofit quite a lot and this error seems plain impossible.

Comment: Well, I gave up using it for now since my project is a bit urgent. I am switching to "ion" and it works well.


I requested server log from my API developer and that log showed that the retrofit error seems to be because of http stack is changed. Thus the server didn't recognised the device with the auth_token anymore. And didn't allow the device to write.

Answer (score 1):

The exception says that something is setting a request header promising a 29149-byte request body, but not delivering that body. If your body is supposed to be 29149 bytes, you need to figure out why it isn't being written. If your body is supposed to be empty, you need to figure out where the `Content-Length` header is coming from.

Comment: Yes, I am sending base64 string and thus the body is supposed to be 29149 bytes. But I have no idea why it isn't being written.